# How export database from mssql by using command line

Tags: sql-server, database, export

I am using windows7 os and i have a database on MSSQL server 2005 i am using following codes to import database

```
sqlcmd -S [server instance name] -d [database name] -i [filename you want to import]
```

i want to export database something like above command if any?

Comment: By "export database" do you mean "backup database" ?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you've the right permissions, try:

```
SqlCmd -E -S Server_Name –Q "BACKUP DATABASE [Name_of_Database] TO DISK=’X:PathToBackupLocation[Name_of_Database].bak'"
```

<sup>Note: Instead of `-E`, you can use `-U` and `-P` to specify user credentials.</sup>

Then to restore, use the following syntax:

```
SqlCmd -E -S Server_Name –Q "RESTORE DATABASE [Name_of_Database] FROM DISK=’X:PathToBackupFile[File_Name].bak'"
```

<sup>Source: [Backup and Restore Your SQL Server Database from the Command Line](https://www.howtogeek.com/50295/backup-your-sql-server-database-from-the-command-line/).</sup>

To export specific data, see: [How to export data as CSV format from SQL Server using sqlcmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/425379/55075)

Answer (score 2):

The -i  is to import a procedure/table/whatever **from** a file and there is a -o  option to output a table/procedure **to** a file.
See
[sqlcmd.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)